# Duplication of charts in published SSRS 2012 reports

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2012

I have a set of 16 charts I need to display for each group in my dataset. I have it working perfectly in the design environment. The charts are in a list control with grouping on one field. Each unique group should result in a set of 16 charts.

The problem only exists after I deploy it. The charts repeat across the screen, even covering the SSRS controls in the browser so I cannot click print, export, etc. (See screenshot)

**Some things I've tried:**
1. Using compatibility mode makes no difference. 
2. Using Chrome browser makes no difference.
3. I removed all charts except one and it worked without the duplication. As soon as I add a second chart, the duplication returns.
4. I have tried putting the charts in a table control instead of a list control but got the same result.
5. I have tried putting the charts in a matrix control instead of a list control but got the same result.
6. I added the charts report as a subreport so that the beginning of the charts portion would begin after page 1. Although page 1 of the report didn't result in coverage of the SSRS controls in the browser, when I get to the first page of the subreport in IE, they still display as in the screenshots.
7. I deployed the report to a local SSRS version 14 server (dev environment only) and this is not a problem at all. The charts look great. The production server is not this SSRS version though (*production server details below*). 
8. I got rid of all objects in the report body that have grouping properties, so no more tablix at all. I had only chart objects and used filters on each one to show the data I needed per chart. Result was the same. 
9. I connected to the production server, opened SQL Data Tools (version 2010) and created a brand new project and report. I put only two charts in it. Deployed the report and got the same chart duplication problem.

**Development Environment:**
- Designing in Visual Studio, SQL Data Tools version 14. The Target Server Version in the Project properties is set to "SQL Server 2008 R2, 2012 or 2014";
 
- In Visual Studio, under Tools, Options, Business Intelligence Designers, the Default Deployment Server Version is set to 11.0;

**Server (AWS-hosted):**
- Windows Server 2012 Standard; 
- SQL Server 2012 Standard;
- SSRS version 11.0.5058.0, running in Native mode;
- Internet Explorer version on the server (where I took the screenshot) is 10.0.9200.22104;
- I have also tried Microsoft Edge with emulation document type set to 'Edge (default)' from my Windows 10 PC. Charts still repeat as in screenshot;
- I have also tried Google Chrome from my Windows 10 PC. Charts still repeat as in screenshot;

**Screenshots:**
[Report Manager - Charts repeat and cover controls]

[Visual Studio/SQL Data Tools - Preview shows perfect charts]

Any ideas how to fix this?? I'm at a loss and really need to get this working. Displaying more than one chart in an SSRS 2012 report should not be so difficult...

**[Edited to:]**
- Add project file as requested by @sasfrog. 
 
- Add a script to create table and populate with cleansed data. 
- [Get both zip files][1] 
- Add [Screenshots][2] of this project file's deployed reports on the server. 
 
 The screenshot shows that when there is just 1 chart object (and nothing else), there is no duplication. 
 
But when I add just one more chart object, the charts duplicate across the screen. I tested using both IE and Chrome; same result in both browsers.

I appreciate your help with this.

*Let me know if there any problems getting the two zip files or seeing the screenshot.*

Comment: I've never seen anything like this before, I've done quite a few reports that are similar and never had an issue. Could you post your design view, I'm not sure if it will help but we have to start somewhere!

Comment: Yep we're going to need to see design view to diagnose this. Also can you replicate in a minimal report with dummy data such that you could share the project?

Comment: @sasfrog - Yes, I'll work on setting up a minimal report with dummy data. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @AlanSchofield - I'll post some screenshots from the design view. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @sasfrog - I edited my original post to include links to a zipped up project file and a zipped up script file to create a table and populate with the dummy data. I tested how a report with just one chart looks and what happens when I add a second chart. That's all the objects in the reports in the project file. I am not using tablix/or any other objects. Yet, when the 2nd chart is added, the deployed report duplicates the charts (new screenshot added to show this). Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AlanSchofield - see comment above to sasfrog. Thanks for your help on this! I'm still totally baffled.

Comment: I built the solution you supplied and everything worked as expected. Differences to your environment is that SSRS is on SQL2016 but switching target to earlier version made no difference. Tried with Chrome and Internet Explorer (11.0.15063.0) on Windows 10 clients. No compatibility mode settings are used. Are any custom renderers installed on the server?

Comment: Thanks @AlanSchofield. It works for me on my local SSRS/SQL2016 version too. The server where the report needs to be deployed in production is not mine nor am I an admin on it, though I am sure my login will allow me to look around. Any idea where I should look for custom renderers? I have done plenty of report dev and SSRS/Native and SSRS/SharePoint installations, but never had to deal with custom renderers. Thanks again Alan.

Comment: Check this link. Compare the dev server with production and see if anything looks different. There are a few common rederers around that somebody may have installed in the past such as Nevron charts, several Aspose rederers, Dundas etc..
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/extensions/rendering-extension/deploying-a-rendering-extension

Comment: Thanks @AlanSchofield. I went through that link and compared the <render> element on the production server to my SQL/SSRS2016 config file. With the exception of some additional renderers in 2016, everything else matched up exactly. I don't see any special ones like Dundas, etc. The Microsoft.ReportingServices.HtmlRendering.dll file has a file version of 11.0.5058.0, and date of 2014-05-15. I'm trying to find out if a later update or service pack updates this file. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm stumped to be honest. I'd bet if you setup a test server running SQL/SSRS2012 it would work though. There must be something odd on the server. I've done dozens of these types of reports over SSRS from 2008 onwards and never had a problem. Sorry I can;t help more, good luck!

Comment: Thanks @AlanSchofield. I appreciate your time and effort. I have been considering setting up my own AWS-hosted SQL/SSRS2012 server to test it. If I do it and discover anything useful for this thread I'll post an update. 

Anyone else out there have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: @AlanSchofield Just a note to let you know I tested it on SQL/SSRS2012 using an Amazon EC2 server (just like the production server). It worked perfectly 'out of the box.' The only difference I see between this test server and the one I am having the problems with is that the new test server is running SQL Server 2012 SP3, and SSRS product version 11.0.6020.0. The 'problem' server is running SQL Server 2012 SP2 (11.0.5058.0) and SSRS product version 11.0.5058.0. Also, IE on the new test server is 10.0.9200.22121 compared to 10.0.9200.22104. I will advise the client to do some updates.

Comment: Post back here, I'd be interested in what you fin.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too old, but i had the same problem, I have modified the ASPX page in Reporting Services: ReportViewer.aspx (Reporting Services\ReportServer\Pages) adding a value for tag  you have to enable AsyncRendering="true" and this solved my problem

[SSRS AsyncRendering config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/metT0.png)