# SSRS 2010 charts/dashboard do not render correctly Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reporting-services-2012

I have created a dashboard (report with a number of charts/graphs and gauges on one page) in `SSRS 2010`. The charts and gauges display correctly when I run the report/dashboard in `SSRS 2010`, however when I deploy the report to our report server the charts are not displaying correctly.. they overlay each other and display double charts.

They display this way in `IE 11`, `Chrome` and `Firefox` when using Reporting services. I have tried rebooting the `Report Server (SQL Server)` and stopping and restarting the `SQL Server Reporting services`, does not fix this issue.

Our company does NOT use `SharePoint` but only `RS viewer`.  Not sure what else to do to fix the problem, any help is greatly appreciated.

**How the Report displays in Reporting Services**
[image: How the Report displays in Reporting Services]

**How it should display**
[image: How it should display]

this is the report design: 
[image]

Comment: Do you have the correct target server version selected in the project properties? I do remember seeing a question similar to this quite some time ago but can't remember the solution. Also, can you post your design.

Comment: I checked the Target Server Version and it is set to: SQL Server 2008 R2 or later.

Comment: Your design appears to be different from your expected output. The two main sections are reversed, have you revised the design since you posted the other screen shots? There appears to be a few posts about this.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0cf683a0-239d-4c47-9ee2-a2d76b131707/ssrs-2008-r2-bug-chart-duplicating-and-unwanted-resize?forum=sqlreportingservices  and heer is the one I remembered from 6 months ago, turned out to be a server Service Pack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43814437/duplication-of-charts-in-published-ssrs-2012-reports

Comment: And another post on the subject. Updating some control worked here. I know this is not your exact scenario but I would check that the SSRS server is running the latest Service Pack http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/MVC/Post/Thread/00aa5924-4284-4416-accb-301ad13c7088?category=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Sorry about that.. I had several versions of the report trying to get one to work... I added the correct design picture.

Comment: Did you check that your server is running the latest service pack?

Comment: we are currently running: 11.0.6607.3         SP3         Standard Edition (64-bit)